# wpf stretch a line when resizing the canvas parent

Tags: wpf, canvas, resize, line, stretch

I have a vertical line and a horizontal one that i want to resize when i dynamically resize my canvas parent. (landmark)

i'd like to have the horizontal line always 25 away from the left and right borders of my canvas and 13 away from the bottom border.

and the same for the vertical line, 25 away from the top and bottom borders and 13 from the left border.

Is there a simple solution?
May I have to change my canvas to another control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just stick the lines in a grid on top of your canvas to get the right behaviour

```
<Grid Width="600" Height="600">
   <Canvas Background="LightBlue">
    // stuff here
   </Canvas>
   <Grid>
      <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="1" 
         Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="25,0,25,13"/>
      <Rectangle Fill="Black" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="Black" Width="1" Margin="13,25,0,25"/>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Much clearer solution than using converters, although I'd recommend a `Margin="25,0,0,25"` on the content Canvas to avoid having it draw on top of the lines

Comment: Maybe drawing on top of the lines is a requirement :)

Comment: and i've set my margin to fit with my Canvas perfectly (i have text for the legend, i've forgot to mention... )
Thx to all of you for your quick answers!!!! ^^

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Converters` based on the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` of your `Canvas` to set the height, width, and position of your `Line` objects

To avoid writing a bunch of individual converters, I have a [MathConverter](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/tag/math-converter/) posted on my blog that can be used for all the calculations.

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">

    <!-- Horizontal Line: 25 from each side, and 13 from bottom -->
    <!-- May need to adjust the Canvas.Top ConverterParameter based on Line height -->
    <Line Height="1"
          Canvas.Left="25"
          Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas, Path=ActualHeight, 
              Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, 
              ConverterParameter=@VALUE-14}"
          Width="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas, Path=ActualWidth, 
              Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, 
              ConverterParameter=@VALUE-50}" ... />


    <!-- Vertical Line: 25 from top and bottom, and 13 from left -->
    <Line Canvas.Left="13" Canvas.Top="25"
          Height="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas, Path=ActualHeight, 
              Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, 
              ConverterParameter=@VALUE-50}" ... />

</Canvas>
```

Because these are all Bindings, they will get refreshed anytime the bound property changes (`MyCanvas.ActualHeight` and `MyCanvas.ActualWidth`)

Comment: your solution seems perfect, I can see the line borders that fits perfectly in the vs designer but the line stays transparent and when I lanch the application, the lin estays transparent.
I'm a newbie here so i have to wait 8 hours to respond to my question.
I'll show you my code in detail when the time comes and also search by myself ^^

Comment: @user1462911 Don't forget to give your Line a color and thickness. I left them out of my code sample to stay focused on the properties that affected the positioning and size.

Comment: and i'll keep your converter which seems very useful and so easy to work with!! i think i'll have to use it later in the same project.

Comment: Yeah i've set the Height, Stroke and StrokeThickness Properties of my Line to 2, White and 2, that's why I don't understand this behavior

Answer (score 1):

Use `Grid` instead of `Canvas` in the case you need to set `Margin`.

For your lines to have space from the borders, go to Properties and use `Margin` in the Layout Area to set the spaces. For your horizontal line set the `VerticalAlignment` to `Bottom` and HorizontalAlignment to `Stretch`. The Margin shall be `25,0,25,13` in this case.

for your vertical line set the `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` an the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`. Margin should be `13,25,0,25`

have luck

Comment: Glad I was able to help you ;)